# How to perform an XI:INCLUDE in Orbeon 4.10 form builder

Tags: include, orbeon

Trying to include a set of common sections and fields in all my forms. Forms were built using the form builder so I tried using the xi:include tag but the page stops working when I put the tag in. It does not matter what href parameter I provide. The form stops working.

Comment: How do you use XInclude? Where does it point to? Do you just include a form from another one? I made that assumption in my answer below.

Comment: I had the intention of putting fields and sections that are common across all forms. You can imagine that as header information on a form that does not change for any form. Hence the model and instance data would be the same. I saw an example in the xforms-sandbox where an xml was included in a similar way. But I was unable to get that to work in my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just include a form into another one: the structure of the resulting document will not be compatible with what Form Runner expects. And that's because a form, or a section thereof, includes parts which belong to the model, and parts which belong to the view.

The main way to reuse parts of a form is to use [section templates](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/section-templates.html).

You can also write [custom model logic](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom-model-logic.html).